# Error: "Variable not in scope: (<>)" with the library optparse-applicative

Tags: parsing, haskell, command-line, optparse-applicative

I was watching a video made by Richard Cook on SafariBookOnline. He builds a command line app with Haskell. In this video, he explains some basic concepts while writing a program to parse command lines arguments.

I am quite new to Haskell, and I can't figure out why this code does not work:

```
dataPathParser :: Parser FilePath
dataPathParser = strOption $
  value defaultDataPath
  <> long "data-path"
  <> short 'p'
  <> metavar "DATAPATH"
  <> help ("path to data file (default " ++ defaultDataPath ++ ")")
```

This code does not work at well:

```
itemDescriptionValueParser :: Parser String
itemDescriptionValueParser =
  strOption (long "desc" <> short 'd' <> metavar "DESCRIPTION" <> help "description")
```

And actually, everywhere I wrote "<>", I got an error where the compiler tells me that:

```
• Variable not in scope:
    (<>) :: Mod f5 a5 -> Mod f4 a4 -> Mod ArgumentFields ItemIndex
• Perhaps you meant one of these:
    ‘<$>’ (imported from Options.Applicative),
    ‘<*>’ (imported from Options.Applicative),
    ‘<|>’ (imported from Options.Applicative)
```

The problem I got is most probably due to the difference of versions of GHC and Optparse-applicative. I use the latest ones.
LTS Haskell 9.12:   0.13.2.0.

But since I am quite new, I can't figure out how to rewrite the code of Richard Cook.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.14.0.0/docs/Options-Applicative.html#t:Parser:

> A modifier can be created by composing the basic modifiers provided by here using the `Monoid` operations `mempty` and `mappend`, or their aliases `idm` and `<>`.

It looks like it doesn't export `<>`, though, so you need to get it from [`Data.Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-):

```
import Data.Monoid
```

... or just:

```
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It may seem trivial for you, but I am beginning with Haskell, and I thought about a problem in the code, not in the imports at all. Thanks again!

Comment: @Alexk Yeah, this is not obvious. It looks like the examples were written for an earlier version of optparse-applicative, which did export `(<>)`, but that was changed for a reason I don't understand: https://github.com/pcapriotti/optparse-applicative/issues/224